# Library not registered, Windows XP

Tags: dll, vb6, registry, dllregistration

Using VB6, I cannot change to VB .NET or anything else.

I'm trying to register a COM Library programmatically in the Form_Load() method of the invoking application.

The method I'm using below works as expected on Windows 7, both x86 and x64.  However when I try and use the same application on Windows XP, I receive the Library not registered error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G8t1.jpg

I have verified that the Library is being registered and it shows properly in the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyDll.Component as well as in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\Mydll.DLL

Here is the code I am using, can anyone tell me why this would be occurring on XP only and how to resolve it?

```
Private Declare Function DllRegisterServer Lib "MyDLL.dll" () As Long
Private Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As       Long
Private Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal lpProcName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcA" (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Any, ByVal wParam As Any, ByVal lParam As Any) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
ReDim ConfigFiles(0)
ReDim ConfigFilesToAdd(0)

libID = LoadLibrary("MyDLL.dll")

Dim pAdd As Long
pAdd = GetProcAddress(libID, "DllRegisterServer")

Dim lResult As Long
lResult = CallWindowProc(pAdd, 0&, 0&, 0&, 0&)

Set IGDep = CreateObject(MyDLL.Component")

End Sub
```

I have performed this process with all manner of permissions including the Administrator account and ensured that I had all permissions on the registry.

Thanks for any help you guys can give.

Comment: DLLRegisterServer is not a window proc, and CallWindowProc expects a window handle (HWND) as the first parameter. Why are you trying to invoke CallWindowProc anyway? DLLRegisterServer is a function, not a handle. This code is simply wrong. `CallWindowProc` expects a window handle and four parameters, not a pointer to a function. This code should never have worked on any version of Windows, and I'd suspect it actually never has; that you're seeing the DLL registered on any system is probably the result of something else registering it.

Comment: Using `CallWindowProc` was a common (horrible) hack used to invoke a function pointer as its implementation will arbitrarily run whatever its passed.

Comment: Unfortunately I am being told to do it this way because "there are sometimes issues with calling DllRegisterServer directly". That was what I was doing originally but I was told I couldn't do it that way. In any case though even when using DllRegisterServer directly I still receive the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: I have discovered that the issue is with the CreateObject() call. On Windows 7 it properly returns an Object/Component that contains everything that the Component should have. However on XP it just creates a generic Object.  Does anyone know why this occurs? Can CreateObject() not be used for specific types on XP?